# Loop Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a simple job with only one step, but in some way the Batch loops from reader to processor and then to reader again. I can't understand why.

This is the structure:

The reader makes a double select on the same database. The first select needs to search in the first table some records in some state and the second select needs to match those results, get some records from the second table and send them to processor that call an api for every record.
I need to stop the batch running at this point, so after the processor. But I have some problems with this.

Example of my batch:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class LoadIdemOperationJob {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @Scheduled(cron = "* */3 * * * *")
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(jobRegistry.getJob("firstJob"), jobParameters);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job firstJob(Step firstStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("firstJob")
                .start(firstStep)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step firstStep(MyReader reader,
                          MyProcessor processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("firstStep")
                .<List<String>, List<String>>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(new NoOpItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MyReader reader(@Value("${hours}") String hours) {
        return new MyReader(hours);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyProcessor processor() {
        return new MyProcessor();
    }


    public static class NoOpItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {
        @Override
        public void write(@NonNull List<?> items) {
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return postProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
}
```

Example of Reader:

```
public class MyReader implements ItemReader<List<String>> {

    public String hours;

    private List<String> results;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public MyReader(String hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> read() throws Exception {
        results = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(// 1^ query, String.class);

        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        List<String> results = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(// 2^ query, String.class);

        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

And Processor:

```
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<String>, List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> process(@NonNull List<String> results) throws Exception {

        results.forEach(result -> // calling service);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the implementation of the [chunk-oriented processing model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) of Spring Batch, where items are read and processed in sequence one by one, and written in chunks.

That said, the design and configuration of your chunk-oriented step is not ideal: the reader returns a List of Strings (so an item in your case is the List itself, not an element from the list), the processor loops over the elements of each List (while it is not intended to do so), and finally there is no item writer (this is a sign that either you don't need a chunk-oriented step, or the step is not well designed).

I can recommend to modify your step design as follows:

- The reader should return a single item and not a List. For example, by using the iterator of `results` and make the reader return `iterator.next()`.
- Remove the processor and move its code in the item writer. In fact, the item processor is optional in a chunk-oriented step
- Create an item writer with the code of the item processor. Posting results to a REST endpoint is in fact a kind of write operation, so an item writer is definitely better suited than an item processor in this case.

With that design, you should see your chunk-oriented step reading and writing all items from your list without the impression that the job is "looping". This is actually the implementation of the pattern described above.